# Enviar y recibir archivo Vue-Resource y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy intentando enviar una imágen mediante vue-resource y recuperarla en un archivo php pero no lo he conseguido, este es mi archivo JS:

```
//* AJAX *//
startAsyncNews: function(){
    if(this.sendimage){
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file",this.contentnew.imageFile );
        console.log(this.contentnew.imageFile);
    }   

    // POST /someUrl
    this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', { 
        data:{action : this.accion_new, data_new: this.contentnew , imgf : formdata}
    }).then(response => {
    }, response => {
        console.log("error");
    });
},
imageSelect: function($event){
    this.sendimage=true;
    this.contentnew.imageFile =$event.target.files[0];  
}
```

Cuando uso el `console.log = console.log(this.contentnew.imageFile);`me muestra las propiedades de la imágen correctamente , es decir está enviando bien el archivo, pero cuando lo recibo en php y le hago vardump me sale asi `object(stdclass)#3 (0) no properties` no properties y con json_decode /encode me sale que esta vacio, también intente sin

```
headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

Pero genera el siguiente error:

> Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST

Comment: Y cómo estás intentando leerlo en PHP?

Comment: haciendo un var_dump

Comment: pero var_dump de qué? de $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar de esta manera:

```
this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', data, {
   emulateJSON: true
})
```

Ese código enviará la solicitud como application / x-www-form-urlencoded.

O puedes usar un FormData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('action', this.action);
formData.append('data_new', this.contentnew)
formData.append('imgf', this.contentnew.imageFile);

this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', formData).then(response => {
    // success callback
  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
```

Trata de enviar todos los parámetros en el formdata no solo el archivo, como en el ejemplo que puse arriba, y manda al post solo el formdata.

Para acceder al archivo mediante php debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$_FILES['imgf'];
```

Si escribes:

```
var_dump($_FILES['imgf']);
```

Te debe mostrar algo como esto:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(31) "serverless-square-icon-text.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpO680V7" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(70686) }
```

Comment: sera que estoy haciendo algo mal? hice tal cual me dijiste, y llegan las variables vacias, pero la de imgf ( imagen file ) ni siquiera llega

Comment: si ya lo estas haciendo como puse en la respuesta entonces estas accediendo mal en el php, para acceder al archivo debes usar $_FILES['imgf'], al hacer el var_dump($_FILES['imgf']) te debe arrojar algo como esto: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(31) "serverless-square-icon-text.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpO680V7" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(70686) }

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario al final decidi usar Axios